# Django: Using __contains with **kwargs filter

Tags: django

I have an attribute, passed in as a string, which I use to call X.objects.filter(**{string: TION}). This would have the effect of returning all objects of type X, whose attribute string, is "TION". Is it possible to do this kind of **kwargs input with an __icontains, __contains instead? How would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just build a string with `__contains` out of your attribute.

More clearly, you want something like:

```
query_type = '{0}__contains'
query_key = query_type.format(string)
X.objects.filter(**{query_key: 'TION'})
```

or just

```
X.objects.filter(**{string + '__contains': 'TION'})
```

Comment: +1, for examples I try to use {0} since {} is only `2.7` and 2.6 is veeery common.